# Xcode 10.1 ImageRow issue

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, eureka-forms

Is there anyone else who is getting error during build process after Xcode upgraded to 10.1? I am trying whole night and day what's wrong and it seems like [ImageRow](https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/ImageRow) is not compatible with newest Xcode?

Swift 4.2
Xcode 10.1
Eureka 4.3.0
ImageRow 3.1.0

Pod file:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'My cashflow' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'ImageRow', '~> 3.0'
end
```

And errors I get after compiling:

[image]

Errors:

```
Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : Any]' with an index of type 'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

'UIImagePickerControllerSourceType' has been renamed to 'UIImagePickerController.SourceType'

Missing argument label 'rawValue:' in call
```

All pods installed and updated (Podfile.lock):

```
PODS:
  - Eureka (4.3.0)
  - ImageRow (3.1.0):
    - Eureka (~> 4.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - ImageRow (~> 3.0)

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git:
    - Eureka
    - ImageRow

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Eureka: 6d711cb30ca333b4bc893110285a722ae3840114
  ImageRow: 1ea483078bfa3d880a7fc76fdfcddfd5f29a9e6b

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 0bae1aabb456725a8d30797929aa85ea96da832c

COCOAPODS: 1.5.3
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what stopped you, I didn't use this pod but I clearly see that you should add `rawValue` in a call because `UIImagePickerController.SourceType` is enum of type `Int` : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/sourcetype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching in the ImageRow known issues and you easily find the answer: https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/ImageRow/issues/51

> For Swift 4.2 use the master branch. There is no release for that yet

So, in your Podfile, use:

```
pod 'ImageRow', :git => 'https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/ImageRow', :branch => 'master'
```

After `pod update`, your Podfile.lock will show the updated dependency as:

```
PODS:
  - Eureka (4.3.0)
  - ImageRow (3.1.0):
    - Eureka (~> 4.0)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - ImageRow (from `https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/ImageRow`, branch `master`)

SPEC REPOS:
  https://github.com/cocoapods/specs.git:
    - Eureka

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  ImageRow:
    :branch: master
    :git: https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/ImageRow

CHECKOUT OPTIONS:
  ImageRow:
    :commit: 6e75b9408bd3393daea467afa73c07cc021a87ae
    :git: https://github.com/EurekaCommunity/ImageRow

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  Eureka: 6d711cb30ca333b4bc893110285a722ae3840114
  ImageRow: 1ea483078bfa3d880a7fc76fdfcddfd5f29a9e6b

PODFILE CHECKSUM: 0e94ba74cfd5e7ee8120ee7410f3045c8e2cbcfc

COCOAPODS: 1.5.3
```

And it will build fine in Xcode 10+.